# Modifying a nested dictionary element by a reference, generated from a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, reference, pass-by-reference

1. The code:

   ```
   def main():
    nested_dict = {'A': {'A_1': 'value_1', 'B_1': 'value_2'},
                   'B': 'value_3'}

    access_pattern = ['A', 'B_1']
    new_value = 'value_4'

    nested_dict[access_pattern] = new_value

    return nested_dict
   ```

---

2. Background information:

As can be seen, I have a variable called ***nested_dict*** - in reality, it contains hundreds of elements with a different number of sub-elements each (I'm simplifying it for the purpose of the example).

I need to modify the value of some elements inside this dictionary, but it is not predetermined which elements exactly. The specific "path" to the elements that need be modified, will be provided by the ***access_pattern*** variable, which will be different every time.

---

3. The problem:

I know how to reference the ***value*** of the dictionary with this function `functools.reduce(dict.get, access_pattern, nested_dict)`. However, I do not know how to ***universally modify*** (regardless of the contained variable type) the value of the ***access_pattern*** in the dictionary.

The provided code produces a `TypeError` that I do not know how to overcome elegantly. I did think of some solution, specified in **4.**

---

4. Possible solutions:

   ```
    if len(access_pattern) == 1:
      nested_dict[access_pattern[0]] = new_value
    elif len(access_pattern) == 2:
      nested_dict[access_pattern[0]][access_pattern[1]] = new_value
    ...
    So on for all len()
   ```

This just seems VERY inelegant and painful. Is there a more practical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of recursion

```
def edit_from_access_pattern(access_pattern, nested_dict, new_value):
    if len(access_pattern) == 1:
        nested_dict[access_pattern[0]] = new_value
    else:
        return edit_from_access_pattern(access_pattern[1:], nested_dict[access_pattern[0], new_value]
```

Comment: you need to handle the cases where access pattern is wrong or key is not present

Comment: @sahasrara62

See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/idiomatic-python-eafp-versus-lbyl/

the edit_from_access_pattern should be as simple as possible. IndexErrors should be caught at a higher level.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
def set_value(container, key, value):
    if len(key) == 1:
        container[key[0]] = value
    else:
        set_value(container[key[0]], key[1:], value)
```

but an explicit loop is probably going to be more efficient

```
def set_value(container, key, value):
    for i in range(len(key)-1):
        container = container[key[i]]
    container[key[-1]] = value
```